# Rigorous proof of one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ being homeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to prove $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} \sim S^1$. Here is my strategy:

We know that $S^1$ is compact, and $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ is Hausdorff. Therefore if $f$ is a bijective continuous map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, then it is automatically a closed map, which would imply it being a homeomorphism.

Now, we define $f$ by the stereographic projection, where $S^1$ is centered at $(0,1)$ and $f$ maps the point $(0,2)$ to $\infty$. It is clear that $f$ is a bijection.

All we need to show is that $f$ is continuous, but here is where I'm stuck at. I know how open sets of the one-point compactification look like, but instead of showing each inverse image of open sets of the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $S^1$ with the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which would be quite tedious and not very fun), I want to know if there is any other *nice* way to show continuity of $f$, which would capture the intuitive obviousness of this situation.

Comment: A neighborhood basis for the point $\infty$, $\{[\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty]\}$, has an easy-to-calculate preimage on the circle under stereographic projection.  Similarly for the open sets $(a,b)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.  Just show that the inverse images of open sets are open (which isn't tedious and might be fun).

Comment: By the universal property of one-point compactification, $S^1$ is the one-point compactification of $S^1\setminus\{(0,2)\}$.  So you only need to show that $S^1\setminus\{(0,2)\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ - and for that you can write explicit formulas for both the stereographic projection and its inverse.  They only involve rational functions, and possible square-root for norms.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks a lot, I was looking for such an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Following you approach, we show that $f$ is continuous.

Let $N = (0,2)$ denote the north pole of $S^1$. It is well-konwn that stereographic projection $s : S^1 \setminus \{N\} \to \mathbb R, s(x,y) = \dfrac{2x}{2-y}$, is a homeomorphism. $f : S^1 \to \mathbb R^* = \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ is a bijective extension of $s$. Since $S^1 \setminus \{N\}$ is open in $S^1$, the function $f$ is continuous in all points of $S^1 \setminus \{N\}$. It remains to show that $f$ is continuous in $N$. So let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $\infty$. It is has the form $U = \mathbb R^* \setminus K$ for some compact $K \subset \mathbb R$. $C  = s^{-1}(K)$ is a compact subset of $S^1 \setminus \{N\}$, thus $V = S^1 \setminus C$ is an open neighborhood of $N$ in $S^1$. By construction $f(V) \subset U$ (simply because the bijection $f$ maps $C$ onto  $K$).